# Icons with a FacesMessage when validating

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, icons

PrimeFaces/JSF 2.0

When you use p:message.... and say your outputText has required="true", you see the error icon in the message displayed to the right of the field if the user leaves the field blank.

```
<!--  NAME -->
  <p:panelGrid styleClass="noBorders" columns="2" columnClasses="inputText" style="width:600px">
   <h:inputText id="Name" size="60" maxlength="70" required="true" styleClass="#{not     component.valid ? 'ui-input-invalid' : ''}" style="width: 300px" value="#{tinRequestBean.name}" >
    <f:validator validatorId="gov.irs.eservices.tm.validations.NameValidator" />
   </h:inputText> 
   <p:message for="Name" display="default" style="color: red" />
  </p:panelGrid>
```

However, if you use a Validator to check the contents of the field in some way, the standard FacesMessage, even with FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, the error icon does not show up.

```
  if (msgStr.length() > 0) {
   FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "TIN: Validation error: "   msgStr, null);
   throw new ValidatorException(msg);
  }
```

Does anyone know a way to create a FacesMessage with an icon attached?  It's certainly not in the constructor.

Comment: This is not a standard JSF feature. This is a PrimeFaces feature. The icon is not definied in standard JSF `FacesMessage` API. The icon is definied in CSS associated with `<p:message>` which changes conditionally based on message severity. As to the concrete problem, are you absolutely sure that the message is been presented by `<p:message(s)>` and not `<h:message(s)>`?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `display="both"` on the `<p:message/>`(or just leave that attribute out altogether, `both` is the default). This will display both the text and the icon. As far as I can tell, `default` is not a valid option